# Using Ansible to setup pair of interdependent servers

Tags: ansible

I wanted to use Ansible to setup two virtual servers: A and B.  A's settings needs IP address and passwords setup on B, and B's settings needs IP address and passwords setup on A.

Since the script will create VM's A and then B, what is the best way to script their setup?  Ansible seems to setup each server independently.  Is the best way to create 2 separate playbooks, where the first creates the VM's and gathers info, and the second configures both servers?  Perhaps saving information to a file in-between?

It seems like a pretty common setup scenarios (eg: clusters) so there must be a well defined way to do this?

Comment: See `hostvars` => https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables.

Answer (score 0):

I used the following approach while I was working on database clusters. There is not a single way to achieve this but the following would give you an idea.

```yaml
- name: Create two virtual machines A,B
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: An API call to create virtual machine
      uri:
        url: API endpoint
        method: POST

    - name: An API call to get information about the vm you just created
      uri:
        url: API endpoint
        method: GET
      register: mongo_server

    - name: Add the host to the inventory
      add_host:
        args: "ssh-common-args='-o StrictHostKeyChecking=no'"
        name: "{{mongo_server.name}}"
        groups: "A"
        ansible_ssh_user: "{{mongo_server.user}}"
        ansible_ssh_pass:  "{{mongo_server.pass}}"
        public_ip_addr: "{{mongo_server.ip_addr}}"
        
- name: Connect A and use B's information in it
  hosts: A
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{hostvars['B'].ansible_ssh_pass}}"

- name: Connect B and use A's information in it
  hosts: B
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{hostvars['A'].ansible_ssh_pass}}"
```

I suggest you to execute first play as a role, that way you can execute it two times to create two virtual machines A and B because the code above only creates one virtual machine, but it would demonstrate the process.  I am not sure how you create your virtual machines but I was using my company's API to create a virtual machine, tag it, and retrieve its information. As you can see, you can add these newly created machines to the inventory and access them through hostvars. Th

Comment: I would be creating VPC's on AWS.  I like the single script approach you have.  Do you add the new host to a temporary inventory?  (I want to throw away inventory once pair is setup_

Comment: Yes, the inventory is built on the execution and it is temporary , not saved.